# how to add frictionless effect to an object on a plane

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and the is working on a personal project. In the following picture, you can see a blue plane in the middle, I want to use it as a ice plane and there should be no friction when user is walking on it. In another way, if I press 'w', the object should move forward until it hits an object. I know there's a built-in function called physic material, but it works only when the plane is tilt at some angle so that the object will slide down from the top to the bottom, but if the plane is placed in a horizontal level it will not work. Anybody has any suggestions for it, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I've seen worse questions although yours will need some editing. +1 for not deserving a negative question rating. What do you mean by physic material, can you point at a doc for this? Normally rigid body config would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering from my phone and off the top of my head, but look at using input.getaxisraw() to get your direction data then add forces. use triggers to stop the movement when you reach a trigger on another object. There were some good tutorials on Collisions and triggers on unity tutorials. To elaborate more, you can add colliders to the objects that you want your player object to interact with physically. So for your player object you can add code like:

```
OnTriggerEnter(collider c) {
// stop movement
}
```